# Why would gnome-system-monitor not show the CPU frequency? (18.04)

Tags: gnome, cpu, ubuntu-gnome, system-monitor, cpufreq

I have Ubuntu 18.04 and I can see my CPU and memory usage in system monitor, but the "Freq" widget remains empty.

I checked some files under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/...` and it looks like you need to be root to read some of these. Could it be that Gnome tries to read some of these files?

According to the table showing the changes between frequencies, my CPUs do change frequency once in a while so it would be cool to see that in the monitor (although since I have 32 cores, I'm not so sure it would be useful if they only display one CPU's Frequency).